# Chart doesn't appear in ASP.NET after DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to display a simple chart in my ASP.NET application.
I've tried creating a chart using arrays in aspx page and managed to do so.
But when i try to display data from the database, nothing happens.

I've followed these instructions:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-ASPNet-Chart-Control-from-Database-using-C-and-VBNet-Example.aspx

Except the part of the ddl. i choose a date and use it for my sql query.
The retreiving from db part works, and according to what i see in debug, so does the binding.
But for some reason, nothing appears.

Here is the code from aspx:

```
<asp:Chart ID="ChartStats" runat="server"  Visible = "false" >
            <Titles>
                   <asp:Title ShadowOffset="3" Name="Items" />
            </Titles>
            <Legends>
                 <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Row" />
            </Legends>
              <Series>
                  <asp:Series Name="Default"></asp:Series>
              </Series>
              <ChartAreas>
                  <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartStatsArea"></asp:ChartArea>
              </ChartAreas>
          </asp:Chart>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
String date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateFrom.Text).ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    string query = "select HOUR_BUCKET, count(START_CALL_COUNT)  from ictappo.traffic_summary t where EVENT_START_DATE=" + date + " group by HOUR_BUCKET order by HOUR_BUCKET asc";


    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("TRAFFIC_SUMMARY");

    ApplicationTables ApplTbl = new ApplicationTables("TRAFFIC_SUMMARY");
    String SQLError = "";
    dataTable = ApplTbl.GetTRAFFIC_SUMMARY(query, ref SQLError);


    int[] x = new int[dataTable.Rows.Count];
    int[] y = new int[dataTable.Rows.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i;
        y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i][1]);

    }

    ChartStats.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

    ChartStats.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
    ChartStats.ChartAreas["ChartStatsArea"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

    ChartStats.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

Please help me

UPDATE:
i also tried to add this line to the loop of x, y (and deleting the dataBINDXY command), but it didn't help:

```
ChartStats.Series["Default"].Points.AddXY(x[i], y[i]);
```

Comment: Where you returing the datatable?

Comment: @Izzy i didn't undersatnd the question.
If your asking where the return od db is happening, it's handled in :
dataTable = ApplTbl.GetTRAFFIC_SUMMARY(query, ref SQLError);

This part works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The problem was with the rendering of the page, this code is ok.